# Polly timeout policy not triggered

Tags: c#, timeout, polly, retry-logic, policywrap

I'm trying to get a Polly timeout policy to execute and it's not working, but when I combine it with a retry policy it works fine. The policies are defined as follows: *(Disclaimer: this is pure test code, ignore code smells)*

```
var httpRetryPolicy = Policy.Handle<TimeoutRejectedException>()
    .OrResult<HttpResponseMessage>(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(
        5,
        retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        (_, _, retryAttempt, _) => Debug.WriteLine($"Retrying ({retryAttempt})")
        );

var timeoutPolicy = Policy.TimeoutAsync<HttpResponseMessage>(
        4,
        TimeoutStrategy.Optimistic,
        (_, _, _, _) => { Debug.WriteLine("Timeout"); return Task.CompletedTask; }
    );
```

The endpoint for the policy/delay test in `PollyTestController` is:

```
[HttpGet("{policyKey}/{delay}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RunPolicyTest(string policyKey, int delay)
{
    AsyncPolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> policy = null;
    if(policyKey == "T")
        policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, Policy.NoOpAsync<HttpResponseMessage>()));
    else if(policyKey == "TR")
        policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, httpRetryPolicy));

    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var url = $"http://localhost:5000/test/{delay}";
    try
    {
       var response = await policy.ExecuteAsync(() => httpClient.GetAsync(url));
        return Ok(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message); 
    }
}
```

And the test endpoint in `TestController` is:

```
[HttpGet("{delay}")]
public IActionResult GetWithDelay(int delay)
{
    if (delay == 10) return NotFound("Not found");

    Thread.Sleep(delay*1000);
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

#### Scenario 1 - call `http://localhost:5000/pollytest/T/6`

This will select the `"T"` policy (timeout) to execute the call to `http://localhost:5000/test/6`. From the code above it's clear that the response will be delayed for 6 seconds, and since the timeout in the policy is 4 seconds, a `TimeoutRejectedException` should be thrown. But that's not happening: The request hangs for exactly 6 seconds before returning with a "Success" response. Nothing is printed to the Output window.

#### Scenario 2 - call `http://localhost:5000/pollytest/TR/10`

This will select the `"TR"` policy (timeout wrapped around retry) to execute the call to `http://localhost:5000/test/10`. Because of the value 10 for the delay, the endpoint will return a 404, so the retry policy will try 5 times with a delay of 1 second between each try. But this time the timeout policy kicks in after the fourth try, the fifth try never happens, the Output window shows:

```
Retrying (1)
Retrying (2)
Retrying (3)
Retrying (4)
Timeout
```

and the response is "The delegate executed asynchronously through TimeoutPolicy did not complete within the timeout."

What am I missing here? Why is Scenario 1 not triggering the timeout policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of optimistic timeout the policy uses a `CancellationToken` to stop the decorated method if the predefined duration is elapsed.

So, all you need is to pass use a different overload of the ExecuteAsync

```
var response = await policy.ExecuteAsync(ct => httpClient.GetAsync(url, ct), CancellationToken.None);
```

- The second parameter of the `ExecuteAsync` is a user-defined cancellation token. If you have your own you can provide it here and Polly will chain that to the Timeout's `CancellationToken`. If you don't have then you can provide None.
- The ct is the Timeout's `CancellationToken` which either a chained or a single token depending on the second parameter of the `ExecuteAsync`

---

**UPDATE #1**

Let's focus on this bit:

```
AsyncPolicyWrap<HttpResponseMessage> policy = null;
if(policyKey == "T")
    policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, Policy.NoOpAsync<HttpResponseMessage>()));
else if(policyKey == "TR")
    policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, httpRetryPolicy);
```

In case of `"T"` you have used the `NoOp`. That policy was designed **for unit testing only**: *test your method like there is no policy*. Having the `NoOp` as the inner policy has the same effect as using the `NoOp` directly, it will not trigger escalation:

```
var noop = Policy.NoOpAsync<HttpResponseMessage>();
var retry = Policy<HttpResponseMessage>.HandleResult(r => !r.IsSuccessStatusCode).RetryAsync(3);
var wrap = Policy.WrapAsync(retry, noop);

var res = await wrap.ExecuteAsync(() =>  {
    Console.WriteLine("Called");
    return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent));
});
```

Output

```
Called
```

So, you have to use only the `timeoutPolicy` if you receive `"T"`. To do that, you have to change the `policy`'s type from `AsyncPolicyWrap<HttpReponseMessage>` to simply `IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>`

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy = null;
if(policyKey == "T")
    policy = timeoutPolicy;
else if(policyKey == "TR")
    policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, httpRetryPolicy);
```

Or

```
IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> policy = timeoutPolicy;
if(policyKey == "TR")
    policy = Policy.WrapAsync(timeoutPolicy, httpRetryPolicy);
```

Comment: I made that change and it didn't work either, I still get a "Success" response long after the 4 seconds specified in the policy. I get that the optimistic timeout works on a separate thread and uses the cancellation token, but if that's what's happening here I don't get why the onTimeoutAsync delegate is never executed in that case. With Pessimistic timeout everything works fine, I think I'll stick to that one until I understand this better.

Comment: @Sam I've updated my answer please check it again.

Comment: Made all the changes suggested and the timeout policy is still not triggered. As I pointed out in my previous comment, changing the TimeoutStrategy to Pessimistic fixes everything. So I will use that strategy and will also use IAsyncPolicy<T> instead of AsyncPolicyWrap<T> to avoid the use of NoOp (that was just a hack). As a side note, the timeout policy was triggered when using the Pessimistic strategy *regardless of whether the NoOp policy was used or not*. Thanks!

Comment: @Sam There must be something else on your side. With optimistic timeout it should work like a charm. [Here is a simple dotnet fiddle app to prove it.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzIklh) I've used [httpstat.us](http://httpstat.us/) for testing.

Comment: Well this is definitely one of those voodoo things that happen sometimes. I ran the same code in my original post except I used the URL in the fiddle (http://httpstat.us/200?sleep=5000) and guess what? it worked like a charm, in all cases: with or without a cancelation token, with or without optimistic timeout. And here's the kicker: I changed the URL back to the original one, and NOW everything worked. Go figure. Thanks for your help, I learned a few things about Polly from your answers.

Comment: @Sam :) I'm glad to read that now it works. Please consider to upvote and/or accept my post as the answer if you have found it useful. Have a great weekend!